# How can 32 teams rotate through 8 games without overlaps?

Tags: optimization

So I have to arrange a rotation schedule for a tournament. We're aiming for 32 teams. There will be 8 stations and 4 teams competing simultaneously at each station. We want all 32 teams to hit each station once, but not play the same teams twice. I was hoping to set up a template so if the teams go up or down it will be an easy fix.

Comment: Can you explain this a little better? I'm not exactly sure what you mean.

Comment: With no other restrictions, it is quite simple, you can just rotate them if you place all stations in a circle. You probably mean that two teams never face each other twice. Then, it is 'simply' a task of constructing 4 mutually orthogonal 8x8 Latin squares - which is possible, because 7 is the maximum according to [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A001438).

Comment: @Glorfindel Can you elaborate on how that would work in an answer? [Here](http://pastebin.com/bGiUGxBM) is a pastebin with 4 MOLS of order 8.

Comment: So I have to arrange a rotation schedule for a tournament. We're aiming for 32 teams. There will be 8 stations and 4 teams competing simultaneously at each station. We want all 32 teams to hit each station once but not play the same teams twice. I was hoping to set up a template so if the teams go up or down it will be an easy fix. This is for the person that needed more detail. Hopefully, this helps

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that two teams may never face each other twice (otherwise, it is trivial), here is a solution. Thanks to @MikeEarnest for providing me with the necessary
[mutually orthogonal Latin squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graeco-Latin_square#Mutually_orthogonal_Latin_squares). Let S1, S2 ... S8 denote the stations, and R1, R2 ... R8 denote the rounds. For convenience, we number the teams A, B, C, D plus a number from 1 to 8. The following configuration would work:

```
   S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6 S7 S8

R1 A7 A6 A5 A4 A3 A2 A1 A8
R2 A6 A7 A4 A5 A2 A3 A8 A1
R3 A5 A4 A7 A6 A1 A8 A3 A2
R4 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8 A1 A2 A3
R5 A3 A2 A1 A8 A7 A6 A5 A4
R6 A2 A3 A8 A1 A6 A7 A4 A5
R7 A1 A8 A3 A2 A5 A4 A7 A6
R8 A8 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7

R1 B7 B5 B3 B1 B4 B6 B8 B2
R2 B6 B4 B2 B8 B5 B7 B1 B3
R3 B5 B7 B1 B3 B6 B4 B2 B8
R4 B4 B6 B8 B2 B7 B5 B3 B1
R5 B3 B1 B7 B5 B8 B2 B4 B6
R6 B2 B8 B6 B4 B1 B3 B5 B7
R7 B1 B3 B5 B7 B2 B8 B6 B4
R8 B8 B2 B4 B6 B3 B1 B7 B5

R1 C7 C4 C1 C2 C8 C3 C6 C5
R2 C6 C5 C8 C3 C1 C2 C7 C4
R3 C5 C6 C3 C8 C2 C1 C4 C7
R4 C4 C7 C2 C1 C3 C8 C5 C6
R5 C3 C8 C5 C6 C4 C7 C2 C1
R6 C2 C1 C4 C7 C5 C6 C3 C8
R7 C1 C2 C7 C4 C6 C5 C8 C3
R8 C8 C3 C6 C5 C7 C4 C1 C2

R1 D7 D3 D4 D8 D1 D5 D2 D6
R2 D6 D2 D5 D1 D8 D4 D3 D7
R3 D5 D1 D6 D2 D3 D7 D8 D4
R4 D4 D8 D7 D3 D2 D6 D1 D5
R5 D3 D7 D8 D4 D5 D1 D6 D2
R6 D2 D6 D1 D5 D4 D8 D7 D3
R7 D1 D5 D2 D6 D7 D3 D4 D8
R8 D8 D4 D3 D7 D6 D2 D5 D1
```

Because every square is a Latin square, each team will visit each station during all the rounds. Each round, you have one A-team (pun intended) and one team from B, C and D on one station. Because they're mutually orthogonal, teams will never face each other in two different rounds. One of the most striking results of this field of combinatorics is that a slightly different configuration, with 12 teams and 6 stations *cannot* be solved. This is Euler's [Thirty-six officers problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty-six_officers_problem).

Comment: Awesome, nice insight, and thanks for humoring me!

Comment: You're welcome. Somehow I didn't like this part of the Discrete Mathematics course I took. Or maybe I just liked the other parts better.

Comment: Yes, combinatorial design feels pretty clunky, it isn't fun to learn about IMO. But it's very cool seeing it used to solve real world problems

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easier to read (but far less insightful) presentation of Glorinfidel's answer. The teams are numbered 1-32. Every row is a list of matches which can happen concurrently.

```
  Station 1    Station 2    Station 3    Station 4    Station 5    Station 6    Station 7    Station 8
 1, 9,17,25 │ 2,11,20,29 │ 3,13,23,28 │ 4,15,22,32 │ 5,12,24,31 │ 6,10,21,27 │ 7,16,18,30 │ 8,14,19,26
 2,10,18,26 │ 1,12,19,30 │ 4,14,24,27 │ 3,16,21,31 │ 6,11,23,32 │ 5, 9,22,28 │ 8,15,17,29 │ 7,13,20,25
 3,11,19,27 │ 4, 9,18,31 │ 1,15,21,26 │ 2,13,24,30 │ 7,10,22,29 │ 8,12,23,25 │ 5,14,20,32 │ 6,16,17,28
 4,12,20,28 │ 3,10,17,32 │ 2,16,22,25 │ 1,14,23,29 │ 8, 9,21,30 │ 7,11,24,26 │ 6,13,19,31 │ 5,15,18,27
 5,13,21,29 │ 6,15,24,25 │ 7, 9,19,32 │ 8,11,18,28 │ 1,16,20,27 │ 2,14,17,31 │ 3,12,22,26 │ 4,10,23,30
 6,14,22,30 │ 5,16,23,26 │ 8,10,20,31 │ 7,12,17,27 │ 2,15,19,28 │ 1,13,18,32 │ 4,11,21,25 │ 3, 9,24,29
 7,15,23,31 │ 8,13,22,27 │ 5,11,17,30 │ 6, 9,20,26 │ 3,14,18,25 │ 4,16,19,29 │ 1,10,24,28 │ 2,12,21,32
 8,16,24,32 │ 7,14,21,28 │ 6,12,18,29 │ 5,10,19,25 │ 4,13,17,26 │ 3,15,20,30 │ 2, 9,23,27 │ 1,11,22,31
```